Solving the summation $ S = \sum_{r=1}^{25} \frac{1}{z^{18r} + z^{9r} + 1} $
Question:
I am trying to solve the following summation problem involving complex numbers:
Given a complex number $z$ satisfying $z^{26} = 1$, and the summation:
$$
S = \sum_{r=1}^{25} \frac{1}{z^{18r} + z^{9r} + 1}
$$
I've attempted to manipulate the terms inside the sum by expressing $z$ as $e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{26}}$, where $k$ is an integer, but nothing fruitful came out.
However, I'm unable to proceed further towards finding a solution. Could someone please provide guidance on how to approach this problem? Any insights or alternative methods for solving the summation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Answer given is $17$

I also tried manipulating the expression, $$
S = \sum_{r=1}^{25} \frac{1}{z^{2r} + z^{r} + 1}
$$
But couldn't solve any further, I had one more idea of clubbing $i$th term and $26-i$th term, but could reduce it to $$
S = \sum_{r=1}^{25} \frac{z^{2r}+1}{z^{2r} + z^{r} + 1}
$$

Edit: 12 instead of 25 and + $(-i)$

Would it work if you write $Z_r^2 + Z_r+1 = (Z_r-j)(Z_r-\bar j)$ ? where $Z_r = z^{9r}$ then you write the sum $$S = -\frac{2 i}{\sqrt{3}}\sum_{r=1}^{25} \frac{1}{Z_r-j}-\frac{1}{Z_r-\bar j}$$

I did tried that but even after breaking into partial fractions like you did, how will we proceed ahead.@A.PI

The powers of $z$ can be considered modulo $26$, and $9$ is relatively prime to $20$, so when the power $r$ modulo $26$ runs in the set of numbers $1,2,\dots,25$, the replacement power $s=9r$ modulo $26$ also runs in the same set. We can thus instead compute
$$
\begin{aligned}
S &= \sum_{0<s<26}\frac 1{z^{2s}+z^s+1}
= \sum_{0<s<26}\frac {z^s-1}{z^{3s}-1}\\
&= \sum_{0<s<26}\frac {z^{27s}-1}{z^{3s}-1}\qquad\text{ use now $t=3s$ modulo $26$}\\
&= \sum_{0<t<26}\frac {z^{9t}-1}{z^t-1}
= \sum_{0<t<26}(1+z^t+z^{2t}+\dots+z^{8t})\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The sum over $1$ is clear, $25$.
We consider now for $k=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ the sum
$$
\sum_{0<t<26} z^{kt}= -1+\sum_{0\le t<26} z^{kt}=-1+\frac{z^{26k}-1}{z^k-1}=-1\ .
$$
So the result is:
$$S=25+\sum_{1\le k\le 8}-1=25-8=17\ .$$

Computer check: Using sage the result is confirmed as follows:
F.<z> = CyclotomicField(26)
sum([1/(z^(18*r) + z^(9*r) + 1) for r in [1..25]])

And we obtain the result $17$.

This is a perfect answer

Thanks alot, this worked like a charm. Appreciate it a alot
